# View meet link to each event created in a google calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

In a laravel 5.8 project user can create new events using my app and then save those events to his google calendar via OAUTH 2 so that he can view, edit or even delete them. new conference data will be added automatically with each created event.
I want to view google meet link with each event created so that guests can click this link to attend the conference

I started by adding event data and creating new conference data and adding its entry point and using Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceSolutionKey class to determine its type which is "hangoutsMeet" and finally I added conference data to the event

Here is the function I am using to create new events:

```
public function doCreateEvent(Event $evt, Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'calendar_id' => 'required',
        'datetime_start' => 'required|date',
        'datetime_end' => 'required|date'
    ]);

    $title = $request->input('title');
    $calendar_id = $request->input('calendar_id');
    $start = $request->input('datetime_start');
    $end = $request->input('datetime_end');

    $start_datetime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i', $start);
    $end_datetime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i', $end);

    $cal = new \Google_Service_Calendar($this->client);
    $event = new \Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
    $event->setSummary($title);

    $start = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $start->setDateTime($start_datetime->toAtomString());
    $event->setStart($start);
    $end = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $end->setDateTime($end_datetime->toAtomString());
    $event->setEnd($end);

    // Create new conference
    $conference = new \Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceData();

    $entryPoint = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EntryPoint();
    $entryPoint->setAccessCode('wx12z3s');
    $entryPoint->setEntryPointType('video');
    $entryPoint->setLabel('meet.google.com/wx12z3s');
    $entryPoint->setMeetingCode('wx12z3s');
    $entryPoint->setPasscode('wx12z3s');
    $entryPoint->setPassword('wx12z3s');
    $entryPoint->setPin('wx12z3s');
    $entryPoint->setUri('https://meet.google.com/wx12z3s');

    $conference->setEntryPoints($entryPoint);

    $conferenceSolution = new \Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceSolution();
    $conferenceSolution->setIconUri(null);
    $conferenceSolution->setKey(new \Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceSolutionKey());

    $conference->setConferenceSolution($conferenceSolution);

    $conferenceRequest = new \Google_Service_Calendar_CreateConferenceRequest();
    $conferenceRequest->setRequestId($request->_token);
    $conferenceSolutionKey = new \Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceSolutionKey();

    $conferenceSolutionKey->setType("hangoutsMeet");
    $conferenceRequest->setConferenceSolutionKey($conferenceSolutionKey);
    $conferenceRequest->setStatus(new \Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceRequestStatus());

    $conference->setCreateRequest($conferenceRequest);

    $event->setConferenceData($conference);

    //attendee
    if ($request->has('attendee_name')) {
        $attendees = [];
        $attendee_names = $request->input('attendee_name');
        $attendee_emails = $request->input('attendee_email');

        foreach ($attendee_names as $index => $attendee_name) {
            $attendee_email = $attendee_emails[$index];
            if (!empty($attendee_name) && !empty($attendee_email)) {
                $attendee = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
                $attendee->setEmail($attendee_email);
                $attendee->setDisplayName($attendee_name);
                $attendees[] = $attendee;
            }
        }

        $event->attendees = $attendees;
    }

    $created_event = $cal->events->insert($calendar_id, $event);

    $evt->title = $title;
    $evt->calendar_id = $calendar_id;
    $evt->event_id = $created_event->id;
    $evt->datetime_start = $start_datetime->toDateTimeString();
    $evt->datetime_end = $end_datetime->toDateTimeString();
    $evt->save();

    return redirect('/event/create')
                ->with('message', [
                    'type' => 'success',
                    'text' => 'Event was created!'
                ]);
  }
```

[image: Event Card]
Event created successfully but no conference data showed on user's google calendar event card so he can not access the new created conference meet link

The question is how can I know if conference data is added to the event successfully although hangout meet link did not show on the event card?

Answer (score 8):

This combination of the answers above worked for me:

```php
$event = new \Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
    'summary' => 'Appointment',
    'location' => 'Earth',
    'description' => 'Hello world',
    'start' => array(
        'dateTime' => Carbon::now()->format('c'),
        'timeZone' => 'Europe/Zurich',
    ),
    'end' => array(
        'dateTime' => Carbon::now()->addMinutes(15)->format('c'),
        'timeZone' => 'Europe/Zurich',
    )
));

$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);

printf('Event created: %s', $event->htmlLink);

$conference = new \Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceData();
$conferenceRequest = new \Google_Service_Calendar_CreateConferenceRequest();
$conferenceRequest->setRequestId('randomString123');
$conference->setCreateRequest($conferenceRequest);
$event->setConferenceData($conference);

$event = $service->events->patch($calendarId, $event->id, $event, ['conferenceDataVersion' => 1]);

printf('<br>Conference created: %s', $event->hangoutLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no information regarding how to show the meet link in calendar event card from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert). You will need to manually insert/input from the comment section the url of Hangout meeting.
I would like to suggest to use the [Events formats](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/events) from Hangouts Chat API.

Comment: By default when conference data added to the event successfully the hangout meet link would appear in event card

Answer (score 0):

```php
 $created_event = $cal->events->insert(
    $calendar_id, 
    $event, 
    ['conferenceDataVersion' => 1]
);
```

Need to set the `conferenceDataVersion => 1` as one in the optional parameter set.